# How do I make hidden information appear below a row rather than next to it?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a table that shows the report name, report path , and the user who ran that report. I have currently added the user information in a column next to report name and report path and I have made it hidden and it only appears when you click on the report name data field. I am looking to achieve the following results : show the report name and report path only once(my current setup shows repeating report names and report paths because different users ran the same reports) and click on it to expand and show the different users that ran it. I believe this could be achievable by grouping but Im not sure how .

More information :

This  is how my tablix looks right now

```
+----------------+---------------+-------------+
| [+Report Name] | [Report Path] | [User Name] |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+
```

The + sign toggles the visibility of [User Name]

However I would like to be presented like so:

```
+----------------+---------------+
| [-Report Name] | [Report Path] |
+----------------+---------------+
| [User Name]    |               |
+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: You'll have to explain your exact problem a little better. As it is currently written, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Does this explain things a bit better or is it still too confusing?

Comment: Share the dataset you are using for the tablix or an example.

Comment: Basically I need something that is almost exactly the same as described here (possible solution) :[link](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2010/3/31/ssrs-multiple-row-grouping-elements-to-appear-under-a-single-column-within-a-table-in-a-report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you express in comments this is a possible solution:

I have this dataset as example:

[image]

Create a tablix with the following data arrangement:

[image]

Select the `User` row and right click it, select `Row Visibility`

[image]

Set the visibility to toggle by `ReportPath`

[image]

In the preview You can show or hide the user based on the toggled by setting:

[image]

Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: Hi Alejandro , this is a very informative answer I have ended up just grouping the user names by the report names and it seems to do roughly what i want it to do. I think the issue is that my data isnt greatly related to each other as other data would be like: Territory->Region->country for example. But thanks for the great effort you p ut in your answer . :) Im sure someone will find this as helpful as i did